# Drag and Drop at particular Location + Occupy space available in Main Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

As You can see in Figure 1 .
I have a Main `div` - which is Droppable

With Four Draggables namely **A** , **B** , **C** , **Fit**.
On drag Of A , B or  C div  into the droppable Main Div - It occupies the space as shown in **Fig 2** *(shows when I drag A into the Main Div )*.Now if I drag another div (A , B or C) then it should occupy the space with respect to their width size. (height is same as Main Div)

Fig 1
[image: Figure 1]

Fig 2
[image]

Now if I drag the 4th draggable `div` i.e with name **Fit** then a `div` should be formed inside the Main `div` with the width equal to whatever space is left in the two adjacent Divs in Main `div`.

*For example :* . Suppose 10px space is between A and B (inside Main) and between B and c , space is 40px , So if i Drop FIT in between A and B then a div should be formed with their space difference i.e 10px , similarly 40px div should be formed in between B and C on drag of FIT

*It shouldn't squeeze the divs present in the Main Div , neither it should overflow Main DIv*

Please Let me know How I can Place the Draggables A, B and C inside the Main `div` at the user positioned location, without Disturbing the Main `div` Width.

What I have done is 
I made div's A , B , C as draggable

```
$(".classname").draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  stop: function(event, ui) {
  }
});
```

and main div Droppable:

```
$(".maindivclass").droppable();
```

and on drop of the draggables , I am making those Divs Draggable inside the main div

```
$("#" + Dropped_div_id).draggable({
  axis: 'x',
  containment: "#Main_divID",
});
```

But on drop of A, B and C , It always occupies the center location and right now I can drop any number of `div`s inside the Main `div`. Please tell me how to make draggables position the exact location where User is dropping and summation of width of all `div`s dropped should be always equal to the Main `div` width. Maybe Grid is the solution, but I have dynamic Width `div`s to drop.

I researched a lot and found something - 10 % relevant to my task is this http://gridster.net/ - But here the container is not fixed height or width. In my case Height of all `div`s are the same. Only width varies.

**More Addtional Info When Asked in comments:**

*1)* When A, B, or C is dragged and dropped to Main, you want the item to be appended into Main.

*2)* When another is dragged, it should not be dropped / overlap on other divs already present in Main.

*3)*  On drag of Fit, Whatever space left in the Main should become occupied. I mean div with respective width should be created as per the space left in Main div

Comment: can you create a fiddle with an example of you real structure?

Comment: @EmanueleParisio I started a basic fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/nkm09x7k/

Comment: @EmanueleParisio yes you can use this jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/nkm09x7k . How to drop the draggables to exact location where user wants and how to avoid overlapping of A, B , C at the time of first drop inside droppable

Comment: Thanks for that fiddle @warkentien2

Comment: @YoYo to make sure I understand this properly, 1) When A, B, or C is dragged and dropped to Main, you want the item to be appended into Main. Yes? 2) When another is dragged, should it be able to be dragged onto of any others already in Main? 3) When Fit is dragged in before or after an other objects, it should expand to the height and remaining width of space between any objects to it's left/right and to corresponding border of Main? 4) Should object be draggable after they are dropped? or stay locked?

Comment: Working on this here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/35nd6y3g/1/

Comment: @Twisty :  1) When A, B, or C is dragged and dropped to Main, you want the item to be appended into Main. - yes you are right .2)When another is dragged, it should not dragged / overlap other divs already present in Main. 3) Yes On drag of Fit , Whatever space left in the Main should become occupied. I mean div with respective width should be created as per the space left in  Main div

Comment: @YoYo you need to be positioned exactly where the user drop them or they will reposition next to the first block present in the container? the first element dropped will always move at the far left of the container? there should be different problem if they must stay in the same location the user drop them.

Comment: @YoYo are you planning to use or are using the JQuery UI Draggable Collision plugin?

Comment: Feel like this is getting close. I have one odd collision bug on when dragging in a new object when objects exist already. https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/35nd6y3g/2/

Comment: Working on that positioning bug and 'fit' still: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/35nd6y3g/6/

Comment: *"On drag Of A , B and C div into the droppable Main Div - It occupies the space as shown in Fig 2"* - that means you dropped all 3 divs into main. But fig 2 only has A. Did you mean to you *or* instead of *and*? *"Now if I drag the 4th draggable div i.e with name Fit then a div should be formed inside the Main div with the width equal to whatever space is left in the Main div"* - So will it overflow main? or will it squeeze everything else together? It's better if you can provide a figure for the desired result as well.

Comment: You should [edit] and update the question with information requested in comments instead of leaving it in comments otherwise everyone will have to read the question as well as long chain of comments to understand what you want.

Comment: @TJ : I have edited the description and answered your query there.I will answer too. " On drag Of A , B and C div into the droppable Main Div - It occupies the space as shown in Fig 2 " yes I meant 'or' , by mistake I wrote 'and'  .   and yes It shouldn't squeeze the divs present in the Main Div , neither it should overflow Main DIv

Comment: @YoYo I still don't understand what is your use case with the `Fit` div. *"a div should be formed inside the Main div with the width equal to whatever space is left in the Main div"* unless the other divs where dropped perfectly next to each other with 0px space between them, having  a div with width equal to the size of entire free space will certainly overflow main/overlap other divs where ever you put it. you're saying you don't want it to overflow either. It is not clear what you want.

Comment: @TJ : I think its very clear .  Suppose 10px space is between A and B (inside Main) and between B and c , space is 40px , So if i Drop FIT in between A and B then a div should be formed with their space difference i.e 10px , similarly 40px div should be formed in between B and C on drag of FIT

Comment: @YoYo So the width of div created by "Fit" should be the space between the adjacent dropped items. But your questions says *" a div should be formed inside the Main div with the width equal to whatever space is left in the Main div"*  that means `50px` size div between A B be will be created (*space is left in the Main div*), which is not possible without overlapping. Hence I said your question is not clear. It is not clear as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was Fun and Dirty.

Made you an example that basically does two extra things:

- Keeps track of the "Dropped" elements positions.
- Calculates the distance between two elements (or sides) when you drop the FIT element.

[**JSnippet "Drag and Fit" :)**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/1067/)

The code obviously need immprovement but I'm sure it will help you get on track.

JS code:

```
$(function() {
    var set = {
        appendClass: 'added',
        area: { s:"#droppable", w:0, left:0 },
        added : [],
    };
    $( ".exact-pos, #drag_fit" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        appendTo: ".wrap",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      accept:".exact-pos, .fill",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $area = $(this);
        var $origin_ele = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        var $ele_clone = $area.closest('.wrap').find('.ui-draggable-dragging').eq(0);
        var mes = {};
        set.area.w = $area.outerWidth();
        set.area.l = $area.offset().left;
        if (!$origin_ele.hasClass("fill")) { // Handle non fit
             mes = { // measure
               s:$origin_ele.attr('class') + " " + set.appendClass,
               l:$ele_clone.offset().left - set.area.l,
               w:$(ui.draggable).outerWidth(),
               r:0
             }
             //Check borders:
             if (mes.l < 0) { mes.l = 0; }
             if (mes.l + mes.w > set.area.w) { mes.l = set.area.w - mes.w; }
             //Set right side:
             mes.r = mes.l + mes.w;
             var revert = false;
             //Check overlaping left:
             $.each(set.added, function(index, ele) {
                if (mes.l >= ele.l && mes.l <= ele.r) {
                   mes.l = ele.r;
                   mes.r = mes.l + mes.w;
                }
             });
             //Check overlapping right: will revert
             $.each(set.added, function(index, ele) {
                if (mes.r >= ele.l && mes.r <= ele.r) {
                    revert = true;
                } else if (mes.r >= ele.r && mes.l <= ele.l) {
                    revert = true;
                } else if (mes.r > set.area.w) {
                    revert = true;
                }
             });
             //append or revert
             if (!revert) {
                ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',false);  
                $area.append($origin_ele.addClass("added").css({"left":mes.l}));
                set.added.push($.extend(true, {}, mes));
             } else {
                ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);  
             }
        } else {
            var f = { l:0,w:0,r:0 };
            var c = $ele_clone.offset().left - set.area.l + ($(ui.draggable).outerWidth() / 2);
            var betw = -1;
            var fleft = 0;
            var fright = 0;
            var revert = false;
            //sort by position:
            set.added.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.l - b.l;
            });
            //after which elemnt:
            $.each(set.added, function(index, ele) {
                if (ele.r < c) { betw = index; }
             });
            //calc dim:
            if (betw == -1 && set.added.length == 0) {
                fright = set.area.w;
            } else if (betw == -1 && set.added.length > 0) {
                fright = set.added[0].l;
            } else if (betw == set.added.length - 1) {
                fleft = set.added[betw].r;
                fright = set.area.w;
            } else if (typeof set.added[betw + 1] != 'undefined') {
                fleft = set.added[betw].r;
                fright = set.added[betw + 1].l;
            }
            if (fright - fleft > 1) {
                f.l = fleft;
                f.w = fright - fleft;
                f.r = f.l + f.w;
            } else {
              revert = true;
            }
            //append or revert:
            if (!revert) {
                ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',false);  
                $area.append($origin_ele.addClass("added").css({"left":f.l, width:f.w}).text(""));
                set.added.push($.extend(true, {}, f));
             } else {
                ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);  
             }
        }
      }
    });
    $('#resetAll').click(function resetAll() {
        set.added = [];
        $(set.area.s).find('div').fadeOut(function(){ $(this).remove(); });
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks pretty promising

Comment: Can you please explain your code , what parameters your are saving and how

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not fully complete, yet it is very functional and I plan on updating it. This currently will perform the following functions:

- Drag an A, B, C, or Fit object into the Main area
- Drag/Move an object that is already in the Main area
- Drag other A, B, C, or Fit object into Main area but not on top of existing objects
- Reset for more testing
- If Fit object is dragged into Main area, and no other objects exist, it will fill the entire area
- If Fit object is dragged into Main area that contains objects, will determine the remaining space between objects and boundry of Main area and will fill the area left or right of existing objects

Current working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/35nd6y3g/10/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box droppable" id="main">Main Div - droppable</div>
  <div class="box draggable new" id="a">drag A</div>
  <div class="box draggable new" id="b">drag B</div>
  <div class="box draggable new" id="c">drag C</div>
  <div class="box draggable new" id="fit" data-width="150">fit</div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
<input type="text" id="leftDetails" style="width: 75%" />
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 450px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  //justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 450px;
}

#main .box {
  background: #9d9d9d;
}

#a {
  width: 30px;
  height: 450px;
}

#b {
  width: 45px;
  height: 450px;
}

#c {
  width: 75px;
  height: 450px;
}

#fit {
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Main: " + $("#main").position().left + " Drag A: " + $("#a").position().left + "Drag B: " + $("#b").position().left + " Drag C: " + $("#c").position().left);
  var mainBoxes = {};
  $("#resetBtn").click(function() {
    $("#main").find("div.box").remove();
    mainBoxes = {};
  });
  var dragOrig;
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: "#main",
    axis: "x",
    revert: true,
    start: function(e, ui) {
      dragOrig = ui.position;
    },
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      $("#leftDetails").val(ui.helper.text() + " pos left: " + ui.position.left + " off left: " + ui.offset.left);
      if (Object.keys(mainBoxes).length === 0) {
        return;
      }
      var offLeft = ui.offset.left - $("#main").offset().left;
      var offRight = offLeft + ui.helper.width();
      //var offMouse = e.clientX - $("#main").offset().left;
      $.each(mainBoxes, function(k, v) {
        if (offLeft >= v.left && offLeft <= v.right) {
          ui.position.left = ui.position.left + v.right;
          console.log("Info: Left Edge collided with ", k, ui.position);
        }
        if (offRight > v.left && offRight < v.right) {
          //ui.position.left = ui.position.left + (v.left - ui.helper.width());
          ui.position.left = ui.position.left + v.right;
          console.log("Info: Right Edge collided with ", k, ui.position);
        }
      });
    },
  });
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    hoverClass: "hover",
    accept: ".box",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      // add functionality here
      //var pos = ui.position;
      var off = ui.offset;
      var c = $("#main .box").length + 1;
      var $newBox = ui.draggable.clone();
      if (ui.draggable.attr("id") === "fit") {
        console.log("Info: Adding 'fit' class");
        $newBox.addClass("fit");
        if (Object.keys(mainBoxes).length === 0) {
          console.log("Info: No other boxes found. Set Max Width.");
          $newBox.css({
            width: "150px",
            height: "450px",
            left: "-1px"
          });
        } else {
          var lefts = Object.keys(mainBoxes).map(function(k) {
            return mainBoxes[k].left;
          });
          var rights = Object.keys(mainBoxes).map(function(k) {
            return mainBoxes[k].right;
          });
          var minLeft = Math.min.apply(null, lefts);
          var maxRight = Math.max.apply(null, rights);
          if ((ui.offset.left - $("#main").offset().left) + ui.helper.width() < minLeft) {
            console.log("Info: 'fit' dropped left of boxes.");
            $newBox.css({
              width: minLeft + "px",
              height: "450px",
              left: "-1px"
            });
            $newBox.data("width", minLeft);
            console.log("Info: ", minLeft, maxRight, $newBox[0]);
          }
          if ((ui.offset.left - $("#main").offset().left) > maxRight) {
            console.log("Info: 'fit' dropped right of boxes.");
            $newBox.css({
              width: (150 - maxRight) + "px",
              height: "450px",
              left: maxRight + "px"
            });
            $newBox.data("width", 150 - maxRight);
            console.log("Info: ", minLeft, maxRight, (450 - maxRight), $newBox[0]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        $newBox = ui.draggable.clone();
        if ($newBox.hasClass("new")) {
          $newBox.removeClass("new");
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
      console.log("Info: Removing .draggable");
      $newBox.removeClass("draggable");
      console.log("Info: Setting ID = box" + c);
      $newBox.attr("id", "box" + c);
      $newBox.draggable({
        containment: "#main",
        axis: "x",
        drag: function(e, ui) {
          if (Object.keys(mainBoxes).length === 0) {
            return;
          }
          var offLeft = ui.offset.left - $("#main").offset().left;
          var offRight = offLeft + ui.helper.width();
          $.each(mainBoxes, function(k, v) {
            if (k == ui.helper.attr("id")) {
              return false;
            }
            if (offLeft > v.left && offLeft < v.right) {
              ui.position.left = v.right;
              console.log("Left Edge Collison with ", k);
            }
            if (offRight > v.left && offRight < v.right) {
              ui.position.left = v.left - ui.helper.width();
              console.log("Info: Right Edge Collision with ", k);
            }
          });
        },
        stop: function(e, ui) {
          mainBoxes[ui.helper.attr("id")] = {
            left: ui.offset.left - $("#main").offset().left,
            right: (ui.offset.left - $("#main").offset().left) + ui.helper.width()
          };
          console.log("Info: Updating ", ui.helper.attr("id"), mainBoxes);
        }
      });
      if ($newBox.draggable("instance") !== "undefined") {
        console.log("box" + c + ": is draggable.");
      }
      $newBox.css({
        left: $newBox.hasClass("fit") ? $newBox.css("left") : (off.left - $("#main").offset().left) + "px",
        top: "-1px",
        position: 'absolute',
        height: "450px",
        width: $newBox.hasClass("fit") ? $newBox.css("width") : ui.draggable.width() + "px"
      });
      console.log("box" + c + ": ", $newBox[0], " now being appended.");
      $("#main").append($newBox);
      mainBoxes['box' + c] = {
        'width': $newBox.width(),
        'left': off.left - $("#main").offset().left,
        'right': (off.left - $("#main").offset().left) + $newBox.width()
      };
      console.log("Added: ", $newBox.attr("id"), mainBoxes);
    }
  });
});
```

As mentioned, this is nearly complete. Due to the use of Viewport Units, positioning is being thrown off. This is not a good use case, but it's what I started with from the fiddle that was offered up.

To track object, I created an Object called `mainBoxes`. This gets updated when an object is dropped into the `droppable`. Each index contains a `left`, `right`, and `width` that is populated from the offset left position value. `mainBoxes is used for collision detection when dragging further objects and to calculate the width for`fit` objects.

We have 2 drag scenarios, dragging a new item into the Main are or moving an item that is already there. When we drag and drop a new item, it is updated, draggable is destroyed, draggable is reset with new properties, and we append it into `#main`. Draggable by default does not append elements, it simply changes it's position on the page. Thus, the `div` would be moved, but would never be a child of `#main`.

The Viewport units created challenges to collision detection and the prevention of dragging an object onto another existing object. I have added lots of details to console for a clear understanding of all the activity. I plan to address this by converting all the lengths and positions to Pixel units.

This should get you going. I also found the following plugin: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jquidragcollide/ I may investigate if this is a better tool to make use of.

Comment: appreciated ...... but yea still it does not look fit for implementation... but i will definitely upvote your answer sir.

Comment: When I have more time, will update. Just a lot of work.